# logstash multiline codec does not work

Tags: logstash

I have configured logstash pipeline to report to elastic. I am able to read the log files. My log files contain multiline messages, but each line is being reported as one message to elastic.Following is my logstash configuration file

LogConf file:

```
input {
        file {
            path => ["abc.log" ]
            start_position => "beginning"
            codec => multiline
            {
                pattern => "^%{LOGLEVEL}"
                negate => "false"
                what => "next"
            }
        }
    }
    filter {

    }
    output {
        # only for debug purposes
        stdout {
            codec => rubydebug
        }
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["http://abcd:9200"]
            index => "logstash"
        }
    }
```

Log file:

```
DEBUG - LogBO={
    message:############ ##############
------------>>!User Info[################################]
------------>>!Debug Info[ ############################# ]
***************isABCEnabled*********************true
}
DEBUG - LogBO={
    message:############ ##############
------------>>!User Info[################################]
------------>>!Debug Info[ ############################# ]
***************isABCEnabled*********************true
}
```

I am able to see the logs getting reported to Elastic, but as each line of log is a separate message. I want whole log

```
DEBUG - LogBO={
    message:############ ##############
------------>>!User Info[################################]
------------>>!Debug Info[ ############################# ]
***************isABCEnabled*********************true
}
```

to be reported as a single message to Elastic.Please help me fixing the issue.

Please help me fixing this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using

```
codec => multiline {
    pattern => "^%{LOGLEVEL}"
    negate => "false"
    what => "next"
}
```

You are telling the codec to join any line matching `^%{LOGLEVEL}` to join with the next line. This will join the first line to the second line because the first line matches `^%{LOGLEVEL}`. The other lines will be ignored and the pattern will not continue matching and joining the same line down. Thus you'll end up with a mess of partial log events.

You will want to use

```
codec => multiline {
    pattern => "^%{LOGLEVEL}"
    negate => "true"
    what => "previous"
}
```

instead. This tells logstash to join any line that does not match `^%{LOGLEVEL}` to the previous line. This ensures that events always start with a `^%{LOGLEVEL}` matching line and is what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Tried as per your suggestion, but this resulted in reporting full log file to elastic. Please help me.

Comment: So it concatenated them all together? This means that the pattern is not matching as it will create a new event every time the pattern is matched. Could there be leading spaces in between the line start and the log level, or some other small difference between the logs and the pattern.

Comment: Exactly !! It was the space issue. Corrected, its working as expected.

Comment: Great! I noticed that their were some spaces at the front of your examples, but at the time i thought that was just a formatting or copy/paste error.

Comment: Here's the complete documentation and examples: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.17/multiline.html see last for your case.